# ASP.Net Printing to printer installed on client machine in a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, printing, foxit, aspose.pdf, neodynamic

This is for ASP.Net website.
When user selects remote documents(pdfs) present on server and clicks print, we need to show the print dialog where user can choose which printer to print to.

The methods which we have tried are:
1. Merge all pdfs, load the resultant on a new window/iframe and invoke print command- The obvious issue here is it takes lots of time when the documents are very large.

2. Aspose pdf print code / Foxit print code - These require some printer to be installed on the IIS server, which is not feasible for us to do.
3. neodynamic - This requires an exe to be installed on client as well, which is not good for us.

Can someone suggest alternatives or what else can be tried?
Is there something obvious that we are missing here?

We heard about browser helper objects, if building these have worked for someone, please help.

Comment: Why don't you stream / load the pdfs into the users browser, then they can print / save as desired?

Comment: User doesnt want to see the pdf before printing. Most common scenario would be select all and print. The user may continue to work on the site while the printer is churning.

Comment: This may be helpful... http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598424/How-to-Silently-Print-PDFs-using-Adobe-Reader-and